# Is sipping super-hot coffee bad?

Tags: health

I drink scalding hot coffee even I have gastric and stomach burning issue. But I love to sip super-hot coffee. Is it a bad addiction to sip hot coffee? Does it harmful for health?

Comment: Do you experience mouth/lip pain or burning while sipping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burning your mouth is obviously the biggest risk when drinking piping-hot coffee. Burning your tongue can lead to destroying taste buds and if you burn it badly enough, you could get an infection on that burn. Further, if I remember correctly, drinking very hot liquids often can contribute to higher levels of mouth cancer.

[HERE](https://www.healthline.com/health/tongue-burn) is some research I found through a quick google.